# Descartando mudanças direto do servidor GIT

Tags: wordpress, git

Guys estou com um problema gigante, digamos que tenho um sistema em maos que foi atualizado via FTP e eu precisava da area do GIT livre sem precisar dar commit no que está diferente do servidor , ou seja de alguma forma deixar o GIT igual ao servidor para que outro analista consiga trabalhar no sistema.

Não sei se minha pergunta foi clara mas estou bem enrolado

o pior que um desses arquivos é atualização do Wordpress via ftp que uma empresa que cuida do banco de dados fez

Comment: deixa ver se entendi, no seu repositório local está diferente do que foi upado pro servidor certo? Porque você não pega os arquivos do servidor e atualiza seu local? Aí não vai reclamar das diferenças

Comment: No caso pegar tudo do servidor , colocar no local e depois subir no git ?

Comment: você tem todos os arquivos no seu GIT certo? (digo repositório local), e alguem upou os arquivos manualmente no servidor, e agora tá dando diferença?

Comment: Exatamente isso , no caso devo pegar os arquivos do servidor via ftp jogar na minha maquina e subir o que ta dando diferente no git ?

Comment: exato. contando que tudo o que tá no seu servidor é o mais atual e é o que deve ser comitado.

Comment: Isso tá tudo certinho no servidor, vou fazer isso e ver se funciona